# Accessibility lost in UITableView subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility

I've walked myself into an accessibility conundrum.

I have a view that required both a grouped-style tableView and (when pressing a UIBarButtonItem) a plain tableView.  The grouped tableView is the default.  I solved this by adding a plain view controller as a subview of the (grouped) tableView, then removing it when flipping back to the grouped tableView.  It works very well.

I'm now implementing voiceover, and running into a problem.  When the plain tableView is shown (a simple list of names), the voiceover text is "empty list" for the entire view.  What's happening is the grouped table view is still there, and empty (zero rows), just hidden behind the plain tableView.  (Technically the plain tableView is a subview of the grouped tableView, using the same CGRect as the grouped tableView so the background is not seen.)

What I'd like to do is "hide" the empty grouped tableView from voiceover, so that taps on the plain tableView become active (speak cell contents).  The `isAccessiblityItem` boolean seems to have no effect.

I do understand a single view with both grouped and plain views is non-standard, but its use here does make sense, so changing the layout isn't an option.

Here's a simplified version of the table flipping code.

Adding the plain tableView:

```
    UITableView *plainTableView = plainViewController.tableView;
    plainTableView.frame=groupedTableViewFrame;
    plainTableView.delegate=self;
    plainTableView.dataSource=self;
    plainTableView.tag=1;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:plainTableView];
    [plainViewController release];
```

Removing the plain tableView:

```
    for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
        if (subview.tag == 1) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview]; //kills the plain view
            self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        }
    }
```

I've attempted adding various `isAccessibilityItem` settings when adding the plain tableView, such as:

```
    plainTableView.isAccessibilityElement=YES;
    self.tableView.isAccessibilityElement=NO;
```

which have no apparent impact.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass a tableView, you can turn off its accessibility with the following:

```
@implementation NonAccessibleTableView

-(BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
    return NO;
}

- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount {
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)accessibilityLabel {
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Addtionally, you might consider making the 2 tableViews siblings that are managed by a single view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `accessibilityElementsHidden = YES`?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/accessibilityElementsHidden

I believe you also have to post a notification using `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` - either layout changed or screen changed should work.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityPostNotification

Comment: You made me to understand that i am forgetting to refer new methods of the SDK @property(nonatomic) BOOL accessibilityElementsHidden NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but perhaps combine setting isAccessibilityElement with sending a UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification or UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification.